# User input more than 1 items and calculate the total price

Tags: c

What do I need to do in order to calculate the total price for the items bought by the user if I allow them to add another item to their cart? Is the value of `chosen1` will change or will it just add that new item without deleting the previous value stored in `chosen1`? Do I have to use array here? I just started learning this and everything is confusing ;<

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 char chosen1;
 int  Qty1;
 printf("Pick your items:\n");
 printf("a-Onions\nb-Leek\nc-Pak Choy\nd-Bell Peppers\ne-Celery\nf-Chicken breast\ng-Chicken thigh\nh-Salmon\ni-Meat\nj-Garlic\n");
 do
 {
 printf("Item?\n");
 scanf(" %c",&chosen1);
 }
 while ((chosen1 != 'a')&&(chosen1!='b')&&(chosen1!='c')&&(chosen1!='d')&&(chosen1!='e')&& 
 (chosen1!='f')&&(chosen1!='g')&&(chosen1!='h')&&(chosen1!='i')&&(chosen1!='j'));
 printf("Quantity?\n");
 scanf("%d",&Qty1);
 printf("Item:%c||Qty:%d\n",chosen1,Qty1);
 printf("Add another item?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables of *scalar* types, such as `char`, `int` or `float` can store only one value at every single moment.
You don't need arrays for this task.
In order to calculate total price you can define a variable of type `float` (it's for numbers with the floating point), and use the operator `switch` to add appropiate amount of money for every item:

```
float totalPrice = 0;
...
float costOfItem;
switch (chosen1)  // we going to appropriate "case" depending on value of chosen1
{
  case 'a': costOfItem = 10.5; break; // here must be cost of onions
  case 'b': costOfItem = 4.0; break;  // here must be cost of leek, etc
  ...
}
totalPrice += costOfItem * Qty1; // here we take the sum of left and right parts of operator "+=" and put it in the left part, i.e. in variable totalPrice
```